# How to configure Spring Security to allow Swagger URL to be accessed without authentication

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

My project has Spring Security. 
Main issue: Not able to access swagger URL at http://localhost:8080/api/v2/api-docs. It says Missing or invalid Authorization header.

[Screenshot of the browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Hl1.png)
My pom.xml has the following entries

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

SwaggerConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("My REST API", "Some custom description of API.", "API TOS", "Terms of service", "myeaddress@company.com", "License of API", "API license URL");
    return apiInfo;
}
```

AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.musigma.esp2" })
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

// ========= Overrides ===========

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

web.xml entries:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.musigma.esp2.configuration.AppConfig
        com.musigma.esp2.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration
        com.musigma.esp2.configuration.PersistenceConfig
        com.musigma.esp2.configuration.ACLConfig
        com.musigma.esp2.configuration.SwaggerConfig
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.musigma.esp2.service", "com.musigma.esp2.security" })
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // custom JSON based authentication by POST of {"username":"<name>","password":"<password>"} which sets the token header upon authentication
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(loginFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // custom Token based authentication based on the header previously given to the client
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(new StatelessTokenAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the security configuration mentioned on [Cannot open Swagger UI in its Version 3 in my Spring Boot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073519/cannot-open-swagger-ui-in-its-version-3-in-my-spring-boot-example) page.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Adding this to your WebSecurityConfiguration class should do the trick.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                                   "/configuration/ui",
                                   "/swagger-resources/**",
                                   "/configuration/security",
                                   "/swagger-ui.html",
                                   "/webjars/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: If you use swagger-ui you need something like this:     .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**","/swagger-resources/configuration/ui","/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()

Comment: In my case this rule is working: .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagge‌​r-ui.html", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security").permitAll()

Comment: Needed more rules: .antMatchers("/", "/csrf", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Is there any security risk allowing access to webjars/** ?

Comment: very helpful answer

Comment: I had to add `.., "/swagger-ui/**"...` to that list

Comment: @FourtyTwo me too, that's because Springfox 3.0.0 was changed the path.

Comment: This list absolutely didn't work for me.

Comment: Could you please add a description of the individual endpoints, why they need to be permitted? I have permitted only `/webjars/swagger-ui/**`, `swagger-ui.html` and `/v3/api-docs/**` and everything seems to be working so far, but perhaps there's some swagger functionality that I overlooked? Or are the `configuration` endpoints only for springfox?

Comment: If you have actuator enable mappings locally and look at the `/actuator/mappings` response to make sure you have covered them all

Answer (score 89):

I had the same problem using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 + Spring Security + Springfox 2.8.0. And I solved the problem using the following security configuration that allows public access to Swagger UI resources.

**Answer updated in January 2021 : support Springfox 3**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- Swagger UI v2
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**"
            // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array
    };


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                // ... here goes your custom security configuration
                authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().  // whitelist Swagger UI resources
                // ... here goes your custom security configuration
                antMatchers("/**").authenticated();  // require authentication for any endpoint that's not whitelisted
    }

}
```

Comment: after adding this class, I'm able to see swagger-ui but APIs are not accessed via postman even with access_token, getting access forbidden error as below, `{
    "timestamp": 1519798917075,
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/<some path>/shop"
}`

Comment: @ChandrakantAudhutwar delete `antMatchers("/**").authenticated()` statement or replace with your own authentication configuration. Be careful, you better know what you're doing with security.

Comment: yes, it worked. I was thinking of only bypassing swagger-ui, but other APIs as it is secured. now my APIs are also bypassed.

Comment: @ChandrakantAudhutwar you do not need to copy-paste the whole `SecurityConfiguration` class to your project. You should have your own `SecurityConfiguration` where you permit requests to Swagger UI resources and keep your APIs secure.

Comment: I have `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` implemented class which makes API' authentication.

Comment: @ChandrakantAudhutwar care to explain how you got around your issue? I can access my swagger page as well but when i hit "Try it" the response body is the login page so it's being redirected

Comment: @ChandrakantAudhutwar it's as if I need to find a way to give swagger a security role so it's not anonymous i see this in my logs:
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1afeff6, returned: -1
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

Comment: I know this answer is old, but if you add "/swagger-ui/**" to the list, it will be perfect. Springfox 3.0.0 URL is that way.

Answer (score 34):

I updated with /configuration/** and /swagger-resources/** and it worked for me.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved the issue.

Comment: This is the one for those using `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui`. Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

For those who using a newer swagger 3 version `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui`

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: If this stops you from getting a "Authentication Required" error, but just shows you a blank page, I also had to add "/swagger-resources/**" and "/swagger-resources" in that list and it fixed it for me.

Comment: for me ```.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll().and()``` was sufficient

Comment: Thanks for posting this; just helped me with Swagger v3.

Answer (score 6):

if your springfox version higher than 2.5， should be add WebSecurityConfiguration as below:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: duliu1990 is right, since springfox 2.5+, all the springfox resources (swagger included) have moved under `/swagger-resources`. `/v2/api-docs` is the default swagger api endpoint (of no concern with the UI), which can be overridden with the config variable `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path` [springfox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger-ui)

Answer (score 6):

Some security config and you are ready with swagger open to all

**For Swagger V2**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CabSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/v2/api-docs", 
            "/swagger-resources/**", 
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security", 
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // ... here goes your custom security configuration
        http.authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll(). // whitelist URL permitted
        antMatchers("/**").authenticated(); // others need auth
    }

}
```

**For Swagger V3**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CabSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- swagger ui
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/v3/api-docs",  
            "/swagger-resources/**", 
            "/swagger-ui/**",
             };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // ... here goes your custom security configuration
        http.authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll(). // whitelist URL permitted
        antMatchers("/**").authenticated(); // others need auth
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tested on v3 and can say this configuration works, but if into requests you need Principal, for example to extract username, then Swagger anyway fails, so I avoid spring boot open api.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Spring Boot 3, you need to use: [`springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui/2.0.2) as it is writen in the [doc introduction](https://springdoc.org/#Introduction).

And use security configuration, something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       return http
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
                       .requestMatchers("/v3/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                       .anyRequest().authenticated()
               ).build();
   }
}
```

- Swagger UI: `http://{your host}:{your port}/swagger-ui/index.html`
- JSON: `http://{your host}:{your port}/v3/api-docs`
- yaml: `http://{your host}:{your port}/v3/api-docs.yaml`

Comment: I want to add authentication to my swagger. what can I do?
So that no one can't see my API list without credentials.

Comment: I feel silly for wandering for so long before finding that I simply had to switch dependencies for Boot 3 (I was still using `springdoc-openapi-ui`)… Too bad this answer is buried under the old Boot 2-focused ones, haha.

Answer (score 5):

More or less this page has answers but all are not at one place. I was dealing with the same issue and spent quite a good time on it. Now i have a better understanding and i would like to share it here:

**I Enabling Swagger ui with Spring websecurity:**

If you have enabled Spring Websecurity by default it will block all the requests to your application and returns 401. However for the swagger ui to load in the browser swagger-ui.html makes several calls to collect data. The best way to debug is open swagger-ui.html in a browser(like google chrome) and use developer options('F12' key ). You can see several calls made when the page loads and if the swagger-ui is not loading completely probably some of them are failing.

you may need to tell Spring websecurity to ignore authentication for several swagger path patterns.
I am using swagger-ui 2.9.2 and in my case below are the patterns that i had to ignore:

However if you are using a different version your's might change. you may have to figure out yours with developer option in your browser as i said before.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", 
            "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
            , "/webjars/**", "/csrf", "/");
}
}
```

**II Enabling swagger ui with interceptor**

Generally you may not want to intercept requests that are made by swagger-ui.html. To exclude several patterns of swagger below is the code:

Most of the cases pattern for web security and interceptor will be same.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class RetrieveCiamInterceptorConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
RetrieveInterceptor validationInterceptor;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    registry.addInterceptor(validationInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**")
    .excludePathPatterns("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", 
            "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
            , "/webjars/**", "/csrf", "/");
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

}
```

Since you may have to enable @EnableWebMvc to add interceptors you may also have to add resource handlers to swagger similar to i have done in the above code snippet.

Comment: Why are you adding `/csrf` in exclusion?

Answer (score 3):

Limiting only to Swagger related resources:

```
.antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**");
```

Comment: for me ```.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll().and()``` was sufficient

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete solution for **Swagger with Spring Security**. We probably want to only enable Swagger in our development and QA environment and disable it in the production environment. So, I am using a property (`prop.swagger.enabled`) as a flag to bypass spring security authentication for swagger-ui only in development/qa environment.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Value("${prop.swagger.enabled:false}")
private boolean enableSwagger;

@Bean
public Docket SwaggerConfig() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .enable(enableSwagger)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.your.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    if (enableSwagger)  
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                               "/configuration/ui",
                               "/swagger-resources/**",
                               "/configuration/security",
                               "/swagger-ui.html",
                               "/webjars/**");
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (enableSwagger) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter it looks like (springdoc-openapi):

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**");
}
```

See [Configuring WebSecurity](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter#configuring-websecurity)

Answer (score 1):

Considering all of your API requests located with a url pattern of `/api/..` you can tell spring to secure only this url pattern by using below configuration. Which means that you are telling spring what to secure instead of what to ignore.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
      .anyRequest().permitAll()
      .and()
    .httpBasic().and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Spring Boot 5. I have this controller that I want an unauthenticated user to invoke.

```
  //Builds a form to send to devices   
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/ViewFormit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
String doFormIT(@PathVariable String id) {
    try
    {
        //Get a list of forms applicable to the current user
        FormService parent = new FormService();
```

Here is what i did in the configuuration.

```
  @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/registration**",
                    "/{^[\\\\d]$}/ViewFormit",
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

Just for enabling Swagger with `Spring boot 2.5.4` and `Springfox Swagger2:3.0.0` the following changes were sufficient for me:-
`.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll().and()`

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions in this thread!

Answer (score 0):

Add a Bean like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
http.authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers(
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-ui/**",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/*/swagger-resources/**",
        "/*/v2/api-docs")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .authorizeExchange()
    .anyExchange()
    .permitAll();
http.httpBasic().disable();
http.csrf().disable();
return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring 3 and Swagger springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.3.0+
I use this config:

```
    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
        "/v2/API-docs",
        "/v3/API-docs",
        "/api-docs/**",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/swagger-ui/**",

};
```

And

```
    @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                    authorizeHttp -> {
                        authorizeHttp.requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll();
                        authorizeHttp.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    });
    return http.build();
```