# Get access to springfox swagger-ui behind spring-security

Tags: spring-security, swagger-ui, springfox

I am going to use springfox (2.6.1v) with swagger-ui in my Spring Boot (1.4.2v).

The configuration for it looks:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .select()
               .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
               .paths(PathSelectors.any())
               .build()
               .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class);
  }
}
```

The problem is that my swagger is behind spring security and I need to allow access there only by admin.

Question is what should be the set of matchers to allow swagger-ui to work within my application?

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("??? <<<what_should_be_here>>> ???") // what should be here?
        .hasRole("TENANT_ADMIN");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut) so following lines:

```
.antMatchers("/admin/system/state/*", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**")
```

But still sth did not work and because of that I have asked this question. But after deeper investigation it occured that spring-fox does not support GSON. When you use GSON as "to json" converter swagger-ui receives a slightly different JSON format what causes problems...

When we changed converter to Jackson and added above paths to spring-config it works without any problems.

I have even requested the new feature on spring-fox github [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1608).