# Configuring swagger for spring boot, spring security JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, swagger

I'm trying to develop Spring Boot REST API and securing it using Spring security with JWT.

I'm using swagger for documenting my endpoints, but I can't have access to file swagger.json.

Swagger get my this error:

```
401 : {"timestamp":1491816380377,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized",
"message":"Authentication Failed: No JWT token found in request headers",
"path":"/api/swagger.json"} 
http://localhost:8080/api/swagger.json
```

This is my WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {

        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider));
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/swagger.json").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

but this rule doesn't work:

```
.antMatchers("/api/swagger.json").permitAll()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut

Comment: I have wrong path, it's work for me thanks. @StanislavL

Comment: I have removed @Bean