# Spring boot and vueJs authentication with firebase

Tags: rest, firebase, spring-boot, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement authentication spring boot in backend and vue Js in front end, the problem is that I have ly backkend connected readonly to a database, so used authentication using vue js and [firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/) feature.

### **The problem is that my endpoints still accessible and anyone can send requests and fetch data using postman for example** !

If anyone has an idea how to resolve that please go ahead, thanks !

PS: i don't think that i may help, but here is my login code anyway, @Renaud Tarnec

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
  name: 'login',
  data: function() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signIn: function() {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
        function(user) {
          alert('You are connected')
        },
        function(err) {
          aler('Ooops,' + err.message)
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here is for example a part of my repo and there is list of events :

```
@RequestMapping("api/events")
public class EventController {
    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventrepository;

    @GetMapping
    public ArrayList<Event> find() {
        ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
        for (Event e : eventrepository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(e);
            events.add(e);
        }
        return events;
    }
```

Comment: You should share your entire code (i.e. add it to your post) for the community to be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for having updated you post. One question: have you set some security rules in your database? If it is Firestore see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview. If it is the Real Time database see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/. As a matter of fact, implementing an authentication mechanism (i.e. with `signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)`) is one part but you have to implement the second part which is authorisation, through a set of rules that restrict the access to your resources to certain users.

Comment: i did that part on VueJs, i will implement it also in spring, will update later , thanks @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is normal behaviour, because you send your request against firestore with the admin sdk credentials.

You need to put some authentication into your spring boot application.

I put some code together that put all your requests behind firebase authentication.

*FirebaseConfig.java*

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="firebase")
public class FirebaseConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirebaseConfig.class);

    private String databaseURL;
    private String serviceAccount;

    @Bean
    public DatabaseReference firebaseDatabse() {
        DatabaseReference firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        return firebase;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        try {
            FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = FirebaseConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(serviceAccount);

                try {
                    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
                            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseURL).build();

                    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
                } catch (IOException ioE) {
                    ioE.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException nullE) {
                nullE.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public String getDatabaseURL() {
        return databaseURL;
    }

    public void setDatabaseURL(String databaseURL) {
        this.databaseURL = databaseURL;
    }

    public String getServiceAccount() {
        return serviceAccount;
    }

    public void setServiceAccount(String serviceAccount) {
        this.serviceAccount = serviceAccount;
    }
}
```

Then you need to enable web security:

*WebSecurityConfig.java*

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);

    /**
     * Use to create instance of {@link FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter}.
     *
     * @return instance of {@link FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter}
     */
    public FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter firebaseAuthenticationFilterBean() throws Exception {
        logger.debug(
                "firebaseAuthenticationFilterBean():: creating instance of FirebaseAuthenticationFilter.");

        FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter();

        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Custom security filter
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(firebaseAuthenticationFilterBean(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

Lastly you add a request filter that validates the access token every time you make a request against the api.

*FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter.java*

```java
@Component
public class FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirebaseAuthenticationTokenFilter.class);
    private final static String TOKEN_HEADER = "Authorization";

    /**
     *
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @param filterChain
     * @throws ServletException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.debug("doFilter:: authenticating...");

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER);

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authToken)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        try {
            Authentication authentication = getAndValidateAuthentication(authToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            logger.debug("doFilter():: successfully authenticated.");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = response;
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            logger.debug("Fail to authenticate.", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param authToken Firebase access token string
     * @return the computed result
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private Authentication getAndValidateAuthentication(String authToken) throws Exception {
        Authentication authentication;

        FirebaseToken firebaseToken = authenticateFirebaseToken(authToken);
        authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(firebaseToken, authToken, new ArrayList<>());

        return authentication;
    }

    /**
     * @param authToken Firebase access token string
     * @return the computed result
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private FirebaseToken authenticateFirebaseToken(String authToken) throws Exception {
        ApiFuture<FirebaseToken> app = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(authToken);

        return app.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        logger.debug("destroy():: invoke");
    }

}
```

Now your API endpoints are save against unauthorized requests.

In you web application you handle the authorization as normally with firebase. On every request to the spring-boot application you pass the access token as `Authorization` header.

Keep in mind that this is not really save, because the spring boot API acts as an admin against the firebase SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i knew that that's what should be done theoriquement but things were somehow mysterious when i implemented it, your answer seems to be way clearer and organised.

Comment: @Kersten, thanks a bunch for this; for months of hitting a deadlock I came across this post and this was very useful. I have made these changes to the codebase, but when I try to access the API through swagger I hit a 403 error. I have added security configuration as per this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut even then it is not working. Any leads ?

Comment: Also just wondering since we have this in the filter how scalable would this be since for every API call we would ping firebase to authenticate the id token.

Comment: @bhavs Sorry, this was just a short mockup from me :) I actually don't use Java so much in my webprojects. You are right with your performance things. Maybe a good idea would be to check the accesstoken only if its not valid anymore. Then it would only call firebase when the token timedout.