# disable swagger-ui based on roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am aware that `swagger-ui` can be fully disabled using `@Profile` on `spring-boot` application but I still want certain privileged user to be able to access `swagger-ui` and not fully disabled.

Is there a way to achieve this.

**update:**

currently I am using `interceptor` approach but i don't want this approach.

```
    @Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {       
    if(request.getRequestURI().contains("swagger") && 
            !request.isUserInRole("XX_YY_ZZ")) {                   

        response.sendError(403, "You are not authorized to access ");            }  
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Springfox for Swagger?

Comment: yes I am using springfox for swagger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without version you use, or codes, it is difficult to help. But I'll try as best as I can.

When you are using swagger-ui, you have an exposed URL to access your docs (usually, `/swagger-ui.html`).
You are using `spring-boot`, and talking about user restriction, so I assume you can use `spring-boot-starter-security`.
With `spring-boot-starter-security`, you can configure easily what URL you want to protect (regarding user roles for instance).

Here is a sample configuration that works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // the rest of your configuration
        http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasRole("DEVELOPER")
}
```

You can secure swagger URLs just like any URLs you expose with your Controllers.

For more information:

- A similar issue:
  [How to configure Spring Security to allow Swagger URL to be accessed without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut)
- Spring security configuration:
  https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

I could help more with:

- An extract of your security configuration
- The version of Spring-boot you're using

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an interceptor or you can handle it in your exiting interceptor if you have any.

In the spring configuration file:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/swager-url" />
        <ref bean="swagerInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="swagerInterceptor" class="com.security.SwagerInterceptor">
    <property name="userService" ref="userService" />
</bean>
```

The interceptor class can be written similar to this:

```
public class SwagerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

       @Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
     //Take out user information from the request and validate
 }
```

Comment: I am doing that currently but i don't like this approach.

Comment: Okay. I see it as a good solution as you have control. Also, there can't be an automated way in swagger to allow a few users and disallow few because of how Swagger will know type of users you want to allow. Thanks.