# How to configure security to allow swagger url to be accessed only with authentication in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, authentication, swagger

I have integrated swagger in node and it is accessible on http://localhost:3002/api-docs. But the swagger ui is publicly accessible. I want to add authentication/security to access this route. When user hits http://localhost:3002/api-docs, it should show popup/prompt to enter username/password. If username and password is correct then only user should able to see swagger UI.

Possibly like as seen in below screenshot

[image]

I am using [swagger-ui-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express), and this is my code that I m using

```
import swaggerUi from 'swagger-ui-express';
import * as swaggerDocument from './swagger.json' 

....
....

app.use("/api-docs",swaggerUi.serve,swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

I searched on the internet but didn't got any solution. I found one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut) but that is in spring.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: [express-basic-auth](https://github.com/LionC/express-basic-auth) can add Basic auth [to individual routes](https://github.com/LionC/express-basic-auth/issues/14#issuecomment-408375330), but I don't know if it can be used together with swagger-ui-express.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can plug in a basic-auth middleware (e.g. https://github.com/LionC/express-basic-auth) to protect the swagger-ui route. If you use `express-basic-auth`, make sure to set the `challenge option` in order to force the browser to open a prompt:

```
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');

app.use("/api-docs",basicAuth({
    users: {'yourUser': 'yourPassword'},
    challenge: true,
}), swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```