# .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll() Doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I want to open the swagger ui on my browser. This is my code

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I still need to enter basic auth provided by httpBasic()

So I add the following code found by others

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**");
    }
```

Now, I can access localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html but the httpBasic window still pops up. I can click cancel to close the window and continue to use the swagger ui. But I don't know what causes the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Spring Security to allow Swagger URL to be accessed without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut)

Comment: Not really, please read my second part of the question.

Comment: Basically I can open swagger UI but the httpBasic() still pops out aftre adding the code

Comment: The issue is caused by secondary files referenced by the main `swagger-ui.html` file, directly or indirectly. Files such as `.js`, `.css`, `.png`, etc. You can see the full list on the Web Browser's "Network" panel. E.g. in Firefox, press F12 and select the "Network" tab, then reload the page. Chrome has similar feature. A request that is returned with status `401 Unauthorized` is what causes the httpBasic popup to occur.

Comment: @Andreas is probably right

Answer (score 0):

From which controller this swagger-ui.html is called put that controller URL to the .antMatchers().

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", 
                     "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", 
                     "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagge‌​r-ui.html",
                     "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", 
                     "/swagger-resources/configuration/security").permitAll() 
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic()
        .and().csrf().disable();
}
```