# How do i disable browser authentication popup in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting browser authentication popup, when I trying to access swagger page.

Spring Boot 3.0.2

[browser authentication popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4jFF.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, you need to disable security checking for Swagger. You can manage [WebSecurityConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.html) for this purpose, for example:

```
@Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
            "/swagger-ui.html/**",
            "/swagger-resources/**")
        .permitAll();
    }
```

You can also check the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut).

Comment: yes, have to disable security checking for Swagger but my application is in spring security 6.0.1. Spring boot 3.0.2

Comment: Seems, have to disable WWW-Authenticate  basic in HttpSecurity.