# How to fix the mixed content error in Swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc, mixed-content

Recently I've moved from SpringFox 2 to Springdoc + OpenAPI 3. It's a bit faster and it works perfectly in my local environment.

When I try to use it in the production environment, the Swagger UI page opens fine. The problem is when I hit the API endpoint, Swagger UI shows this error message:

[image: Error in Swagger UI]

The error in the browser console is:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<myproductionUrl>/swagger-ui/index.html#/Ravel/getLabelFormats' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://<myproductionAPIUrl>/labels?language=10&includeData=false'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I enabled CORS in my Spring Boot project:

```java
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
}
```

This is my Pom file:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.79.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

My `application.yml` file configuration:

```yaml
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: true
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
  api-docs:
    path: /v3/api-docs
```

Java 8
Spring Boot 2.7.8

I don't know what configuration I've forgot. Can someone orient me?

Comment: What's the error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Hi @Helen, I´m looking into the Console and this message show


Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<myproductionUrl>/swagger-ui/index.html#/Ravel/getLabelFormats' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://<myproductionAPIUrl>/labels?language=10&includeData=false'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can enabled https or what configuration is missing ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Interesting. Is `http://<myproductionAPIUrl>` or the use of `http://` hard-coded anywhere in your code/configs? I think in your case the API base URL in Springdoc/Swagger UI configs is supposed to be set to `/` (i.e. the server root) so that Swagger UI will send API calls to exactly the same server/protocol from where it's served.

Comment: Maybe the suggestions here will help? -> https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/118

Comment: Hi, @Helen thank you so much, it a little works now, I put some configuration from your last response, and addition from this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut)

I have a question if it´s possible set manually headers for all EndPoints ? I mean that if it is possible that from code all Apis have for example a specific header ("customheader":"value")