# I can't access the swagger url with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Spring Security in my project, now I am trying to create a documentation with Swagger OpenAPI and I keep suffering with the conflict that this is causing. I don't know what I have to change, because no tutorial allows me to resolve the error. All my attempts to access send me the error 403.

Here my spring security configuration

```
package com.mariojunior.todo.config;

import com.mariojunior.todo.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter;
import com.mariojunior.todo.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter;
import com.mariojunior.todo.security.JWTUtil;
import com.mariojunior.todo.service.UserDetailsService;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST = {
            "/users/",
            "/login"
    };

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST ={
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**"
    };


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());

        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();



        http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
            request.requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll();
            request.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PUBLIC_MATCHERS_POST).permitAll();
            request.anyRequest().authenticated().and().authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        });

        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(this.authenticationManager, jwtUtil, userDetailsService));
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(this.authenticationManager, jwtUtil));

        http.sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }



}
```

I tried to resolve with new links at the whitelist and refactoring with everything that I found about this error, but nothing works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Spring Security to allow Swagger URL to be accessed without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671125/how-to-configure-spring-security-to-allow-swagger-url-to-be-accessed-without-aut)

Comment: request.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll(); You can also consider fixing it with .

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of Spring Boot or security, swagger may not work well.

If you are using an older version of Swagger, try switching to the next version of Swagger.

```
//build.gradle
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui', version: '2.1.0'
```